# Fancybox3 iframe scrolling

Tags: fancybox-3

I want fancybox add scrollbar for iframe if content s higher then my definition, The code belllow does not work:

```
$(".class").fancybox({
      iframe : {
        css : {
          width             : "1000px",
          height              : "600px"
                }
            },
      scrolling         : "yes",
      closeClickOutside : false,
      type                  : "iframe",
      afterClose        : function(){location.reload(); return;}
    });
```

Comment: Is it really so hard to create a working demo?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".class").fancybox({
    iframe : {
            css : {
                width : "1000px",
                height : "600px"
            }
            scrolling : 'yes',
        },
    closeClickOutside : false,
    type : "iframe",
    afterClose : function(){location.reload(); return;}
});
```

You should place the `scrolling : 'auto',` inside the `iframe` option param.

Comment: It does not work, I had to change the .js file and it works